# Oracle SQL: Show n rows for each id

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, top-n

I have a table with 2 columns, ID and URLS, for each ID there are several URLS. I want to extract only 5 maximum URLS per ID. How do I go about doing this in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one,

```
SELECT ID, URL
FROM
    (
        SELECT ID, URL,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY URL DESC) RN
        FROM   tableName
    ) a
WHERE RN <= 5
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ebda0/3)